# JSF 2.0 session returns null at times

Tags: jsf, session, jsf-2

In my JSF 2.0 application, I have a sessions coped User bean where I am setting Siteminder request header values into session variable using the below code :

```
FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    Map<String, String> requestHeaderMap = context.getExternalContext().getRequestHeaderMap();
context.getExternalContext().getSessionMap().put(GlobalConstants.SITEMINDER_USERID, userId);
    context.getExternalContext().getSessionMap().put(GlobalConstants.SITEMINDER_USERGROUPS, groups);
    context.getExternalContext().getSessionMap().put(GlobalConstants.SITEMINDER_USERNAME, userName);
```

From my filter under doFilter method, I am reading the session variable using

```
HttpSession ses = req.getSession();
```

but the ses returns NULL and my filter fails authorization. Can anybody tell me what is going on here ? This does not happen always, happens to 1 in every 10 users. One more information is that the application is on a weblogic server with 2 managed instances for load balancing. So I am not sure if session is resetting to null when the first request gots to one instance and the second one goes to the other instance

Comment: The method getSession() might returns a valid session, if it exists, or return a null if there is no valid HttpSession associated with the HttpServletRequest. If you get a null, this means that it is a new request or the previous session had expired, etc.

Answer (score 0):

One thing that could be happening is that your App is not Shared Session Enabled.

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E15051_01/wls/docs103/webapp/sessions.html

And because its load balanced maybe one managed server doesn't have the session started (on memory) by the other managed server.

Configure the proper weblogic.xml or the weblogic-application.xml to enable the session sharing via memory, cache, etc.

Other possibility it's to configure your Load Balancer to use Sticky Sessions that depends of the Appliance/Software of the Load Balancer.

http://dev.fyicenter.com/Interview-Questions/JavaScript/What_does_the_term_sticky_session_mean_in_a_web_.html

Greetings.